# Trigger the reload/stop button during AJAX requests

Tags: javascript

In the context of an Single Page Application, there's a need to allow the user cancel certain AJAX calls.

In normal server-side site navigation, if the user clicks the wrong link, he can just have the browser stop, and then click a different link, however, it is a problem for user experience when a link is mistakenly clicked, and you cannot cancel loading the next page.

I'm talking about this button:
[image: reload]

The only client-side application that I've seen that partially does this is [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com), where (although briefly), you will get a [image: cancel] icon, but it doesn't seem to allow "cancelling" per se either.

I've search the web across solutions for this, but I couldn't find any, so I'm resorting to S.O. to see if anyone knows how to approach this problem (other than, you know, `<button id="cancel">&times;</button>`)

Thanks.

Comment: As far as I was aware you cannot cancel an ajax request once it's been sent. Why this is the case I don't know, but I would certainly love to be proved wrong!

Comment: More than actually cancelling the request, this is more related to allowing the user to actually control the page with that button (e.g. Cancel navigating to the next view, for example)

Comment: Why [abort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#abort%28%29) does not work for you? Present a cancel button to the user to call it and undo any changes you did on the page your self. With every async stuff that can go on a browser you should not expect to it easily detect all changes you performed on the DOM or the javascript environment it self soo it can rollback that once the user "cancel" an "AJAX call".

Comment: @Prusse: This question is specifically aimed at controlling the state of the Loading/Reload/Stop button and/or detecting changes on it. I'm aware that adding a 'cancel' button to the interface would be analogous to this and would serve the same purpose